# Insert Records repeatedly faster

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

I'm monitoring a folder for Jpg files and need to process the incoming files.
I decode the filename to get all the information I want and insert into a table and then move the file to another folder.

The file name is already contains all the information I want. Eg.

```
2011--8-27_13:20:45_MyLocation_User1.jpg.
```

Now I'm using an `Insert` statement

```
Private Function InsertToDB(ByVal SourceFile As String, ByVal Date_Time As DateTime, ByVal Loc As String, ByVal User As String) As Boolean

    Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(My.Settings.ConString)
    Dim sSQL As String = "INSERT INTO StageTbl ...."
    Dim cmd As SqlComman
    cmd = New SqlCommand(sSQL, conn)

    ....Parameters Set ...

      conn.Open()
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
      conn.Close()
      conn = Nothing
      cmd = Nothing
    End Function
```

The function will be called for every single file found.

Is this most efficient way? Looks like its is very slow. I need to process about 20~50 files/sec. Probably a stored procedure?

I need to do this as fast as possible. I guess bulk insert not applicable here.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Bulk insert could be applicable here - do you need them to be in the DB instantly, or could you just build up the records in memory then push them into the database in batches?

Are you multi-threading as well - otherwise your end to end process could get behind.

Another solution would be to use message queues - pop a message into the queue for every file, then have a process (on a different thread) that is continually reading the queue and adding to the database.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things you can do to optimize the speed of this process:

- Don't open and close the connection for every insert. That alone will yield a (very) significant performance improvement (unless you were using connection pooling already).
- You may gain performance if you disable autocommit and perform inserts in blocks, commiting the transaction after every N rows (100-1000 rows is a good number to try for a start).
- Some DB systems provide a syntax to allow insertion of multiple rows in a single query. SQL Server doesn't but you may be interested on this: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/06/08/sql-server-insert-multiple-records-using-one-insert-statement-use-of-union-all/
- If there are many users/processes accessing this table, access can be slow depending on your transaction isolation level. In your case (20-50 inserts/sec) this shouldn't make a big difference. I don't recommend modifying this unless you understand well what you are doing: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29  and  http://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms173763.aspx .
- I don't think a stored procedure will necessarily provide a big performance gain. You are only parsing/planning the insert 20-50 times per second. Use a stored procedure only if it fits well your development model. If all your other queries are in code, you can avoid it.
- Ensure your bottleneck is the database (i.e. moving files is not taking a lot of time), but since the OS should be good at this, check the points above. If you find that moving files is your bottleneck, delaying or moving files in the background (another thread) can help to a certain extent.